# Smooth visualization of a 3D solid using X Y Z coordinates

Tags: matlab, 3d, smoothing, surface

I have a matrix containing all X Y Z values of points representing a solid body. How can I visualize the solid body smoothly using matlab?

Comment: You would need to have the points indexed in some sort of meaningful way. If the points represent a convex object then you could use `delaunay` and `trisurf`. If it's not convex then this is a non-trivial/ill-posed problem. There is literature available on approximating a surface from a point cloud.

Comment: The Point Cloud Library (PCL) is a powerful opensource C++ library that has MATLAB bindings and could be used for this purpose. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40382-matlab-to-point-cloud-library